# Maven Packaging

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-3

I have a spring boot app version 2.7.0 and java version 17.

I have made a shared dependency and push to local maven dependency jfrog.

Then I have included this dependency to my app

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>utils-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Whenver I run `mvn clean package` I get

> Package does not exits

It seems mvn does not see the package but IntelliJ Idea does.

But when I run with Intellij Idea, it runs well but `mvn package` fails

Can someone help?

Comment: Exactly what output do you get when you run `mvn package`? Please copy and paste it instead of typing it by hand.

Comment: IntelliJ Idea probably performs workspace resolution instead of actually downloading the dependency

Comment: what is `local maven dependency jfrog`? Is it jfrog artifactory installed somewhere in enterprise and you have a dedicated space there to deploy your release artifacts? In that case you need to setup `virtual repository` (not sure about jfrog terminology) which include both "maven central proxy" and "your dedicated space" and setup that repository as `mirror` in your `~/.m2/settings.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found problem.

The package `(utils-starter)` I created had this plugin

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

So removing it solved the problem